# GetObject for meta:resourcekey not being called in IResourceProvider

Tags: globalization, resx, resourceproviderfactory

I need to move a site's .resx files to a database and implement a Custom Resource Provider using the `IResourceProvider` interface. I have followed the example at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.iresourceprovider.aspx

When I call:

```
this.GetLocalResourceObject("myResourceKey.Text")
```

The `GetObject` method in the `IResourceProvider` is called correctly.

However the whole site is using `meta:resourcekey="myResourceKey"` attributes for all of the labels, and the `GetObject` method is not being called for these. There are no other methods in the `IResourceProvider` that I can see to implement, is there something I'm missing, or is there another way I can move the .resx data to the DB and not make any changes to the view, i.e. still keep using the `meta:resourcekey` attributes.

Many thanks

Comment: My problem is the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987929/using-implicit-expressions-with-custom-resourceproviders)

Answer (score 0):

I have found MSDN articles concerning localization lacking in information. Check out Rick Strahl's  implementation of a custom resource provider at:

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbResourceProvider/

and

https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.Globalization

He explains in detail the process he took in writing his resource provider and that should give you a good start